# Can JSON dump help in REST API documentation generation?

Tags: json, rest, postman, openapi, openapi-generator

I have a REST service written in C++/Qt. I'd like to create REST API documentation (using application like Postman for Open API) in order to help a front-end developer who will create rich-client app based on Vue.js. Is it possible to minimize efforts using JSON feed (output from some REST methods)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use swagger? You can generate openapi 3 json and then use swagger tools to generate the UI or stubs.

There is also the [inspector tools](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-inspector/) (but is is pro) that should be what you need.